# Python: Multiply 2D array with each row of another 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, mask

Suppose I have the following data:

```
mask = [[0, 1, 1, 0, 1]] # 2D mask
ip_array = [[7, 4, 5, 2, 3]
            [3, 2, 1, 9, 0]
            [1, 8, 6, 3, 1]] # 2D array
```

I want to multiply the `mask` with each row of `ip_array`. So the output should be like:

```
[[0, 4, 5, 0, 3]
 [0, 2, 1, 0, 0]
 [0, 8, 6, 0, 1]]
```

I am new to numpy functions and I am looking for an efficient way to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `np.multiply(mask, ip_array)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
np.multiply(mask, ip_array)
```

Giving you:

```py
array([[0, 4, 5, 0, 3],
       [0, 2, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 8, 6, 0, 1]])
```

Also, as a heads-up, you're missing two commas in your definition of `ip_array`. It should look like this:

```py
ip_array = [[7, 4, 5, 2, 3],
            [3, 2, 1, 9, 0],
            [1, 8, 6, 3, 1]] # 2D array
```